# How to filter via search with two components [reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Need the `card` component to communicate with the `search` component to filter results.

At the moment the `data` comes from a local JSON file with the following format

```
[
  {
    "title": "example",
    "description": "example",
    "author": "example",
    "date": "2021-01-01",
    "featuredImage": "/example.jpg",
    "categories": "example",
    "tags": "example",
  }
]
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card';
import Search from './components/Search';
import Data from './data/data.json';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [DataFile, setDataFile] = useState(Data);
  const [Search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [Result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const searchChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSearch = () => {
    setResult(Data);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Search onChange={searchChange} onSearch={onSearch} />
      <Card data={DataFile} Result={Result} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Search.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Search = ({ onChange }) => (
  <input
    type='search'
    placeholder='Search...'
    className='search'
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);

export default Search;
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {data.map((x) => (
        <div >
          <h1>{x.title}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

I've confused myself with the React hooks. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong with the state?

Comment: I can't see the card function component in your App. React can just pass the props from parent to child component. Vice versa is not possible.

Comment: I've amended the code. Yes you're correct however I'm confused as to how to update the state so that the search works correctly with the card component.

Comment: Change `const Card = ({ props }) => { ` and `{props.Result.map((x) => (` try this way the map in your card component.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I console.log Result I get an empty array.

Comment: Can you create a working CodeSandbox that demonstrates the error you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added the data to component to make it clear for you

```
    const App = () => {
     //here we define data 
      const data = [
     {
      "title": "example",
      "description": "example",
      "author": "example",
      "date": "2021-01-01",
      "featuredImage": "/example.jpg",
      "categories": "example",
      "tags": "example",
    }
  ]
      //here is where we keep search result
      const [Result, setResult] = useState(null);

    //here we filter the list where the title(or any element of data) is equal to input value
      const searchChange = (e) => {
       const searchResult = data.filter((element) => element.title 
.includes(e.target.value))

      //here we set the filtered list to result
        setResult(searchResult);
      };
      return (
        <>
          <Search onChange={searchChange}/>

          //here we check if result exists if yes pass it to card else pass the data instead
          <Card data={Result!==null?Result:data}/>
        </>
      );
    };
```

i commented the information about the code so you can read them